# DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged doesn't execute when original value is reset using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, dropdown

Initialization of the control is as:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStudent" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStudent_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip" ToolTip="Select student" />
```

Here is the VB code for SelectedIndexChanged event(in VB):

```
Public Sub ddlStudent_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlStudent.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim dsStudentInfo as DataSet = New DataSet()
        If (ddlStudent.SelectedIndex > 0) Then
               dsStudentInfo = GetStudentInfo(Convert.ToInt32(ddlStudent.SelectedItem.Value))
        End If
End Sub
```

When we reset the drop-down index using JQuery, it resets the dropdown index.
And again when we select the previous index, it doesn't trigger server side SelectedIndexChanged event.

Here is the JQuery code to reset the dropdown:

```
$("[id*=ddlStudent]").prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

Here is the demonstration:

- Let us suppose, the dropdown has 4 values i.e. "Please Select Student", "Tim", "Phony" and "Rocky".
- Now user selects "Phony" and then he resets the dropdown, it hits the JQuery code and sets the index to 0.
- But now when user selects "Phony" again, it doesn't hit the server side SelectedIndexChanged event.

**NOTE:**
**I have already tried with the following but it didn't work:**
1. set dropdown "AutoPostBack" property to true
2. __doPostBack("<%=ddlStudent.ClientID %>", '');

Kindly help in finding the solution.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918628/asp-net-vb-net-dropdownlist-selectedindexchanged-not-firing-with-onchange-java). Without seeing the HTML code, I'm curious if you've set the 'OnSelectedIndexChanged' attribute in the HTML? Alongside this, have you set the 'AutoPostBack' to true? This is the solution for the related question.

Comment: I have already tried with the following:
1. set dropdown "AutoPostBack" property to true
2. __doPostBack("<%=ddlStudent.ClientID %>", ''); It didn't work.

Comment: Would you be willing to post the relevant HTML code where you initialise the dropdown?

Comment: Try adding the attribute OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStudent_SelectedIndexChanged". The dropdown has never been binded to the actual function.

Comment: Here is the code that initializes the dropdown: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStudent" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStudent_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip" ToolTip="Select student" />

Answer (score 0):

set dropdown "AutoPostBack" property to true

Comment: I have already tried with the following: 1. set dropdown "AutoPostBack" property to true 2. __doPostBack("<%=ddlStudent.ClientID %>", ''); It didn't work